# Global keyboard shortcut (inittab?)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut that will run:

```
shutdown -h now
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>, for example.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Comment: Debian sid, running XFCE. I would prefer to have the shortcut run regardless of whether or not X / XFCE has been started though (I sometimes use the machine as a server). Which is why I thought inittab might work.

Comment: Bear in mind that bindings listed in `inittab` can be overridden by your WM/DE/OS. If you want it to be truly global, you will need to also configure your environment to allow it to act as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two such shortcuts on the Linux console. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> sends the SIGINT signal to `init`; this triggers the `ctrlaltdel` action in [`inittab`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=inittab&sektion=5). This action usually triggers `/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -r now` (reboot now); change that to `/sbin/shutdown -t1 -a -h now` if you want to halt instead. The other shortcut is the `KeyboardSignal` [console key](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=keymaps&sektion=5) (bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> by default, but you can change that in your console keymap), which triggers the `kbrequest` action in inittab.

Note that these bindings may not be triggered while you're in X. Under X, you can use your window manager's key binding features, or another program such as [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html). Note that under X, you don't get a free pass to run commands as root; if you want to trigger a reboot without entering a password, you'll need a `NOPASSWD` entry in `sudoers`.

(Aside: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> looks awfully easy to type by mistake. It's also a keyboard shortcut in several applications. Pick something rarer and with two modifiers!)

Answer (score 3):

Something pretty similar does probably already work: see [SysRq key sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) (see also [the Linux kernel documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt)). Some variant of `REISUB`, maybe `REISUO` (`O` for poweroff instead of `B` for reboot) could be what you want.
Not as quick and versatile as a way of binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to *any* command, but a possibility.

Comment: This is neat, up-voted you for it.